# "Next number" scenarios using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, pessimistic-locking

I have been playing with Entity Framework and so far I like using it a lot. But everything I've done so far assumes optimistic locking which works well for me in most cases. However, I have the following scenario:

1. A SQL Server table with only one row that holds application-wide data
2. The row contains a column named "NextAvailableNumber"
3. The Application needs to read the number, increment it by 1, and update it

The above has to guarantee that any competing process has to wait to get a number until the first transaction has completed. Previously we have done this using table locks (since there's only one row), but I would like to know how this should be done using LINQ to Entities?

Thanks,

Jim K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement this in stored procedure because and use explicit row locking (or table locking as you mentioned). Then you will call that procedure from EF. I don't think that this can be handled from application code unless you are using serializable transaction every time you work with your special table. It can have huge negative impact on application's performance.

We are actually doing something similar but our table contains plenty of rows for different sequences so I'm using stored procedure with row lock and update lock. We first wanted to call this procedure in insert method of our repository but after that I moved it into database and I call my procedure from  after insert trigger. The reason for this was to deffer row locking to the time of real insertion to database not to the time of marking the entity for insert in EF context (insert itself and procedure call must be in the same transaction in our case). I modified my EF model so that related property has StoreGeneratedPattern set to computed. After each insert EF will requery DB to get assigned sequence number. The only drawback is that EF will also requery DB after each update of these entities but in our case it already do this because of timestamp. This is still in phase of testing and evaluating so I can still change my mind and reimplement it.

Comment: I have a stored procedure already that does something similar that I could leverage and this may be the way I have to go. It's not a fixed requirement, but I wanted to see if its possible to create an application that could be self-contained (code first) and with no stored procedures. I was hoping there was some mechanism within EF to address this scenario since I anticipate that I will have similar needs down the road. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution that we are using, and you can use to avoid to use Store Procedures, specially if you are using EF Code First like us. Code First doesn't support the use of Store Procedures.

The solution is using SqlQuery Method of EF inside the scope of transaction, you have to write a query that first do an update of the next number counter, and then select It . The code will be:

```
string query = "UPDATE Registre_Counter SET Counter = Counter + 1 WHERE CounterName = @p0 AND Year = @p1;";
query += "select * from Registre_Counter Where CounterName = @p0 AND Year = @p1";

GenericCounter GenericCounter = CoreDBContext.Instance().GenericCounter.SqlQuery(query, new Object[] { _counterName, _year }).SingleOrDefault(); //Updates the counter and return de NextNumber to Use
```

The Update will lock the counter and avoid reads from other transactions on it until the transaccion is aborted or commited.

Answer (score 0):

Since Entity framework uses optimistic locking, it will throw an exception when the next number is changed by a second process. The most primitive way to counter this situation will be catch the exception and redo the change until the change is successful. [you can add a timeout to this to ensure that the code execution moves forward in the worst case scenario]

Comment: This is something I was considering but in the end it just doesn't "feel" right. I find that I usually take a step back to reconsider what I'm doing whenever I find myself looking at anything that is timer based. Even though this will be low volume and the likelihood of contention is minimal, I'd still like to know the best practice for this scenario in an EF environment. Thanks for the response.

Comment: In that case, currently the only other solution is to make a custom Stored Procedure and use it to implement the row locking and use it via the Entity Model.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm resigned to using the sproc  mentioned in the comment to @Ladislav Mrnka. Thanks for the help.